# What is the Guava equivalent of Scala's flatMap?

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming, guava

Looking through https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained I see operations like [transform](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform-java.util.List-com.google.common.base.Function-), which will transform a list but keep the same cardinality. How can I perform a transform that results in a different cardinality? e.g. (pseudocode) `List(1,2,3).transform(i => List(i, i))` -> `List(1,1,2,2,3,3)`

Comment: Since when is valid Scala a pseudocode? :)

Comment: @Natix I think Scala is actually more flexible in terms of syntax than pseudocode :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As of version 13, there is [`transformAndConcat`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/13.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#transformAndConcat(com.google.common.base.Function)) on [`FluentIterable`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/13.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html).

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there's a direct translation, but `transform` followed by [`concat`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat-java.lang.Iterable...-) should be equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

In [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/), `collect()` is the equivalent of Scala's `map()`, and [`flatCollect()`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/RichIterable.html#flatCollect-org.eclipse.collections.api.block.function.Function-) is the equivalent of Scala's `flatMap()`.

Here is an example usage of flatCollect [with Java 8 Lambdas](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections-kata/blob/solutions/company-kata/src/test/java/org/eclipse/collections/companykata/Exercise6Test.java#L79).

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to one thing, though: Scala's map methods return new collections, while the transform() method in Guava returns a transformed view of the original collection. This is a very subtle difference. You need to decide whether the 'view over original collection' is appropriate for your context.